# Which magnoliophyta groups are NOT pollinated by bees and why?

Tags: evolution, ecology, taxonomy

Considering the bees as the family Apidae which families of flowering plants are definitely not pollinated by them and what could be the reasons?

-Could you say that the relationship is preserved at the family level?

(Please suppose that both groups live in the same geographic context)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it also sounds like a homework question (and a good one). What research have you done to try to answer it? Can you give us a few examples of why plants might *not* rely on bees for pollination?

Comment: Not a homework question. Actually is part of my PhD research.  I'm looking for putative ecological relations on taxonomic groups that co-occurre in the same place and nearby regions (less than 10km distance). I looked for the families of flowering plants that are always present every time a member of the family Apidae has been found.

Comment: The result is a long list of many families. I was wondering if there there is a family that it is very known that is not pollinated by bees (Apidae). That's why I did that question.

Comment: This is the list:

Comment: Amaryllidaceae
Iridaceae
Hypoxidaceae
Asparagaceae
Orchidaceae
Pontederiaceae
Commelinaceae
Smilacaceae
Melanthiaceae
Liliaceae
Eriocaulaceae
Poaceae
Cyperaceae
Juncaceae
Bromeliaceae
Arecaceae
Hydrocharitaceae
Juncaginaceae

Comment: Potamogetonaceae
Alismataceae
Dioscoreaceae
Musaceae
Lythraceae
Onagraceae
Myrtaceae
Melastomataceae
Cannabaceae
Rhamnaceae
Rosaceae
Moraceae
Urticaceae
Magnoliaceae
Zygophyllaceae
Krameriaceae
Begoniaceae
Cucurbitaceae
Resedaceae
Brassicaceae
Caricaceae
Cleomaceae
Piperaceae
Saururaceae
Aristolochiaceae
Simaroubaceae
Rutaceae

Comment: Anacardiaceae
Sapindaceae
Burseraceae
Meliaceae
Opiliaceae
Loranthaceae
Santalaceae
Schoepfiaceae
Hydrangeaceae
Cornaceae
Loasaceae
Berberidaceae
Papaveraceae
Ranunculaceae
Menispermaceae
Lauraceae
Convolvulaceae
Solanaceae
Hydroleaceae
Asteraceae
Campanulaceae
Polygalaceae

Comment: Fabaceae
Salicaceae
Hypericaceae
Linaceae
Passifloraceae
Euphorbiaceae
Malpighiaceae
Violaceae
Erythroxylaceae
Putranjivaceae
Picrodendraceae
Podostemaceae
Boraginaceae
Rubiaceae
Asclepiadaceae
Gentianaceae
Apocynaceae
Cistaceae
Malvaceae
Bixaceae
Talinaceae
Chenopodiaceae
Polygonaceae
Caryophyllaceae
Plumbaginaceae
Amaranthaceae
Nyctaginaceae
Cactaceae
Phytolaccaceae
Portulacaceae

Comment: Sorry! I think I should reformulate my question.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Flowering plants [evolved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowering_plant) before [bees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee#Evolution), so clearly in the ~100 million years, they must have been pollinated by other methods. Some plants still retain this ancestral characteristic.

[This paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/314099) shows a species *Magnolia tamaulipana* (Magnoliaceae) which is pollinated by beetles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the source! But, in this case, could you call the feature: "Not pollinated by apids (Apidae)" is an ancestral characteristic?